# Open Php variable in Html from a previous session file .php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm creating a Server Side php Website application.
In my first page , the whole code is php , and I've set

```
$_SESSION["lang"] = 'lang.en.php';   
$_SESSION["lang"] = 'lang.it.php';
```

When I change flag, I change a variable :

```
 if (Trim($_SESSION["lang"])=='')
      {
      include 'lang.it.php';
      }
 if (Trim($_SESSION["lang"])=='lang.en.php')
      {
      include 'lang.en.php';
      }
 if (Trim($_SESSION["lang"])=='lang.it.php')
      {
      include 'lang.it.php';
      }
```

I have the following problem

My second page .php is 50% html and 50% php because in html I put a simple dropdown menu.

My Question is : How can I pass to html my variables from another php page without using Jquery?

```
<li> <a class="active" href="home.php"><?php $home?></a> </li>
```

Variable $Home is stored in        - lang.it.php -

How di I access to my variables?

P.s.
I don't want to pass all Menu's variable in the session because I think is crazy to do..

EDIT -- 
   html

```
<head>
<link href="Css/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
</head>
<body>
<center ><div id="header"><center >
 <ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="home.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="download.php">Area Download</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn" 
            onclick="myFunction()">Men&#249;</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
      <a href="/Page1.php">VARIABLE 1 HERE</a>
      <a href="/Page2.php">VARIABLE 2 HERE</a>
       <a href="/Page3.php">VARIABLE 3 HERE</a>
    </div>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<center ><div id="Realbody"><center >
<center ><div id="Footer"><center >
</html>
<?php
require_once("rpcl/rpcl.inc.php");
//Includes
use_unit("forms.inc.php");
use_unit("extctrls.inc.php");
use_unit("stdctrls.inc.php");
use_unit("styles.inc.php");
include 'parameters.php';
//Class definition
class PaginaDownload extends Page
{
    public $Label1 = null;
    public $LoginCss = null;
    function PaginaDownloadShow($sender, $params)
    {
   if ((empty($_SESSION["name"])) || (empty($_SESSION["user"])))
        {
        header('Location: \index.php');
        }
    }
}

global $application;
global $PaginaDownload;
//Creates the form
$PaginaDownload=new PaginaDownload($application);
//Read from resource file
$PaginaDownload->loadResource(__FILE__);
//Shows the form
$PaginaDownload->show();
?>
```

I've to replace VARIABLE 1 , 2 , 3 with my variable on Lang.php

```
 <li><a class="active" href="home.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="home.php"><?php $home?> </a></li>
```

That's my try :

```
//Includes
use_unit("forms.inc.php");
use_unit("extctrls.inc.php");
use_unit("stdctrls.inc.php");
use_unit("styles.inc.php");
use_unit("Zend/zauth.inc.php");
include '/parameters.php';
if (Trim($_SESSION["lang"])=='') { include 'lang.it.php'; }
else
include Trim($_SESSION["lang"]);
//Class definition
```

and here my lang file

```
<?php
/*
------------------
Language: English
------------------
*/
//Login Page #1/X
$title_page_Login = 'Login';
$Err_1_Login = 'Login Credentials Incorrect';
$Err_2_Login = 'Not Found User :';
$Err_3_Login = 'Database Offline';
$Err_4_Login = 'Insert User & Password';
$Err_5_Login = 'Need User';
$Err_6_Login = 'Need Password';
$req_user = 'Insert Username';
$req_pass = 'Insert Password';
$Bt_Label = 'Sign In';
//-------------------
//Home
$home = 'Home';
?>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where this code is: `if (Trim($_SESSION["lang"])=='')
      {
      include 'lang.it.php';
      }`..............

In which file did you write this?

Comment: in page 1 -> if you click england flag 
($_SESSION["lang"]) =lang.en.php

Comment: in page 2 i have the session value of the phpfilename , but i don't know how to write the variables in html

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on how your code is organised, but maybe you can do something like this in page2: if (isset($_SESSION["lang"])) { include $_SESSION["lang"];  } else { include 'lang.it.php';  }

Comment: I try but it don't work....
My 2nd page is <html></html> and at the end <?php ?>
If i put that code in php it forget the include at the next line when i close it

Comment: Can you post your code so that I can check it please?

Comment: I edit my answ with info

Comment: @Furma94 You `include` or `require` the file where you set the variables and write `<?php echo $home ?>` instead of `<?php $home ?>`

Comment: OK, but I don't see the code I suggested

Comment: Usually when you include a file, all the variables that you have defined in that file's "public" scope will also be available in the scope where you did the include.

Comment: Updated post on new quest

Comment: You need to put the code that includes the lang file **before** you use the variable, otherwise it won't exist when you try to use it. Put the code at the start of the file.

Comment: @Andreyu i try to do this many times, but next it avoid all my php code.
IDK WHY , BUT NOW IT WORKS ._. Thank you a lot to refresh me ideas .... btw i don't understand why at first don't work...i try to do like this and it dont work , btw really appreciate to refresh me tx!

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help :)

Comment: OK NOW I FIND THE REAL PROBLEM!!!
THE real problem was this !!!!
echo
I forgive to use it <?php echo $home ?>